# Is this part of the script is safe from sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this part of the script  is safe from sql injections? Because i used this

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key)
{
  $clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST[$key]));
}
```

the  guide of web said it should work  more effectively and faster.

```
<?
    session_start();
    include("db.php");

    if(empty($_POST['token']) || $_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']){
      exit("Error!");
    }
    unset($_SESSION['token']);


    foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key)
    {
      $clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST[$key]));
    }
    $name=$clean['name'];
    $country=$clean['country'];
    $ip=$clean['ip'];
    $map=$clean['map'];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you `unset` the session token?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is save in case you put it in quotes (in mysql query).. However, I'd change foreach to

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  $clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($value));
}
```

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Removed. I forgot to remove them before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent SQL injection easily and get good habits, you should check [parameterized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) using PDO or mysqli.